# improve this graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Please how to make this graph large and a space in $\pi/2$,... like in this picture

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} 

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[width=9cm,height=4cm, 
axis lines = middle, 
grid=both, 
minor tick num=5, 
ticklabel style={fill=white,font=\scriptsize, inner sep=1pt}, 
xmin=-365, xmax=365, 
xtick={-360,-270,-180,-90, 0, 90, 180, 270,360}, 
xticklabels={ $-2\pi$,$-3\pi/2$,$-\pi$, $-\pi/2$, 0, $\pi/2$, $\pi$,$3\pi/2$,$2\pi$ }, 
ymin=-2, ymax=2, 
ytick={-2,-1,...,2}, 
legend style={draw=none,fill=none, font=\scriptsize, 
anchor=north east, at={(1,1)}, 
legend columns=-1}, 
domain=-360:360, 
samples=181, 
no marks\addplot +[red,thick] {tan(x)}; 
\addplot +[blue,thick] {cot(x)}; 
\legend{$\tan(x)$, $\cot(x)$} 
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image][image]

Comment: To post a code, select it and press `ctrl+k`.

Comment: there is no actual question here. put a question in the text of the post, what do you want to change

Comment: I edited my message

Comment: As I see, you actually adopted my answer from your previous question (no up-voted, not accepted :-( ). It is not clear, what you like to have: (i) two pictures (one for tangents, one for cotangents, or (ii) just increase image width. In later case you can for example instead of `width=9cm` use `width=\linewidth` as `axis` options.

Comment: @zarko  for exemple  pi/2 is on the line i want a space as in the picture

Comment: @PolineSandra, you not like to have grid with horizontal lines, only vertical at multiples of pi/2? An only one, common diagram for tangens and contanges function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly. Do you like to have something like this?

[image]

Above diagram is obtained by (all changes in comparison to your MWE are marked by `% <---`):

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=12cm,height=6cm,  % <--- determine size of image
    axis lines = middle,
    axis on top,                     % <---axes and grid id draw over function curves 
    grid=both,
    minor tick num=3,
    ticklabel style={fill=white,font=\scriptsize, 
                     inner sep=1pt, minimum height=1em}, % <--- all ticks labels has 
                                                          % the same baseline (are vertical aligned)
    xmin=-365, xmax=365,
    xtick={-360,-270,...,360},
    extra x ticks = {0},             % added is tick at $x=0$, 
                                     % it write "0" at coordinate origin
    xticklabels={ $-2\pi$,$-\frac{3\pi}{2}$,$-\pi$, $-\frac{\pi}{2}$, 0, 
                  $\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\pi$,$\frac{3\pi}{2}$,$2\pi$ }, % <--- ticks at \pi/2 are write as fraction $\frac{\pi}{2}$
    ymin=-2.2, ymax=2.2,
    ytick={-2,-1,...,2},
    legend style={draw=none,fill=white, fill opacity=0.75,      % <--- added fill opacity, 
                                                                 % now the grid is visible through legend bode
                 font=\scriptsize, text opacity=1, inner sep=1pt, % <--- text is not transparent
                  anchor=north east, at={(1,1)}, legend columns=-1},
    domain=-360:360,
    samples=181,
    no marks
            ]
\addplot +[red,thick] {tan(x)};
\addplot +[blue,thick] {cot(x)};
\legend{$\tan(x)$, $\cot(x)$}
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
In above code are in comparison to your MWE changed the following:

- Increased is the width of image (from 9cm to 12cm). At document classes as is `article` ... it can be for example equal to `\textwidth` with setting `width=\linewidth`.
- Axes and rid are moved on the top of diagram, With this labels are more clear visible.
- In the ticks labels style is determined equal minimum height  of label nodes. With this all labels lie on the dame baseline.
- Angle fraction is write as `$\frac{\pi}{2}` etc (with this labels become shorter in comparison with `$\pi/2$`.
- To the legend style is added `fill=white` with transparency `fill opacity=0.75`. This enable to see trough fill a grid in the  background. For better visibility of text in legend, text transparency is removed by `text opacity=1`.
- All these changes are marked in the code, as already mentioned and now also done in the my answer on your previous question.

Comment: yes that's what i want thank you very much , what you added please ?

Comment: @PolineSandra, I will do asap, however, it can be easy discover with comparison your and mine MWE :-)