# Printing a picture made with TikZ has a different result from what it looks in PDF mode?

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, printing

I have made a lot of pictures with TikZ, but when I print some of them (for example `y = tan x`) there are extra lines on the paper, that don't really exist in construction and PDF mode.
Edit:
I thought that it was unnecessary to post the whole code. Here it is, with the printing result as well (you can find it [**here**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a5QSQxTIKp7XFw0w6hJ-gSLLPG_qsW0u/view?usp=share_link)).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xgreek}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[mathup=sym]{unicode-math}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes,arrows,backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{scopes,svg.path,shapes.geometric,shadows}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{shadowtext}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\setmathfont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{STIX Two Math}
\usetheme{Warsaw} 
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[appendixframenumber]
\useoutertheme[headline=authortitle]{miniframes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\definecolor{ballblue}{rgb}{0.13, 0.67, 0.8}
\definecolor{Red}{RGB}{168, 4, 4}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{DejaVu Sans} 
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
        \draw[thick,->] (-5.1,0) -- (5.1,0)node[pos=1,right]{
        $x$};
        \draw[thick,->] (0,-4) -- (0,4)node[pos=1,left]{$y$};
    \node[below right](o) at (-0.1,0.1){$0$};
        \begin{scope}
        \clip (-5.1,-4) rectangle (5.1,4);
       \draw[dashed](-1.57,-4)--(-1.57,-0.8);
       \draw[dashed](-1.57,-0.1)--(-1.57,4);
       \draw[dashed](1.57,-4)--(1.57,4);
       \draw[dashed](4.71,-4)--(4.71,4);
       \draw[dashed](-4.71,-4)--(-4.71,4);
        \draw[ultra thick, Red, domain={-1.5 }:{1.5}, samples=200] plot(\x,{tan(((\x))*180/pi)});
        \draw[ultra thick, Red, domain={-4.7 }:{-1.7}, samples=200] plot(\x,{tan(((\x))*180/pi)});
        \draw[ultra thick, Red, domain={1.6 }:{4.7}, samples=200] plot(\x,{tan(((\x))*180/pi)});
        \end{scope}
     \node[below]() at (-3.14,0){$-π$};
     \node[below]() at (3.14,0){$π$};
     \node[below]() at (-1.8,0.1){$-\dfrac{π}{2}$};
     \node[below left]() at (4.9,0.1){$\frac{3π}{2}$};
     \node[below right]() at (1.32,0.1){$\dfrac{π}{2}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: we can not debug code that you have not shown

Comment: Please (i) extend your code fragment to complete small document beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` , (ii) `scriptsize` is not environment but switch from one font size to `\scriptsize` fonts, (iii)  as example, how to draw similar diagrams see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/525911/.

Comment: Can you take a photo from your paper? Since the tan functions jumps from +inf to –inf, I could imagine TikZ producing unwanted lines but they would be in the PDF as well and not only on paper.

Comment: Hello. Please provide a compileable MWE. How is “Red” defined? Also provide a screenshot af what you see. When I reduce your code to something compileable I do not see any extra lines.

Comment: (i) why you not insert your image in `frame`? (ii) you use `unicode` math fonts, but not declare them. Consequently tick labels are incomplete and wrong, (iii) your image is simpler and correct draw using `pgfplots` package (which is based on the `tikz`).

Comment: After your editing  of question it is easy going to lost in preamble. Do you really need all this packages in presentation? Some packages are already loaded by beamer (`graphicx` and `hyperref`). To my opinion is more promising way start with my first example  (it is simpler and more reliable than your example) in my answer and step by step add from showed preamble only for your presentation necessary packages.

Answer (score 1):

- You use unicode math fonts, but not declare them. Consequently tick labels are incomplete and wrong also in pdf viewer. For example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
    \usefonttheme{professionalfonts}    % <---
\usepackage{unicode-math}               % <---
    \setsansfont{Verdana}               % <---
    \setmathfont{XITS Math}             % <---
```

- However, if for tick labels you use standard math symbol for `\pi`, you not need above font declarations and can compile MWE in pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX as well in LuaLaTeX as is done in MWE below.
- In `beamer`  documents contents are usually in frames. Why you not insert your image in frame?
- Your image is simpler to draw using `pgfplots` in preamble package (which is based on the tikz). For example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
% in case that you like to compile only with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, 
% uncomment the the following code lines:
%    \usefonttheme{professionalfonts}    % <---
%\usepackage{unicode-math}               % <---
%    \setsansfont{Verdana}               % <---
%    \setmathfont{XITS Math}             % <---

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}                           % <---
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    height=88mm,
    axis lines = middle,
    axis on top,
    xlabel=$x$,                         
    ylabel=$y$,
    label style={anchor=north east},    % <---
    ticklabel style={font=\footnotesize,% <---
                     fill=white, inner sep=2pt},
    xmin=-300, xmax=330,
    xtick={-270,-90,90,270},            % <---
    xticklabels={$-\frac{3\pi}{2}$,$-\frac{\pi}{2}$,    % <---
                  $\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\frac{3\pi}{2}$},   % <---
    ymin=-2.2, ymax=2.2,
    ytick=\empty,
restrict y to domain=-10:10,            % <---
    domain=-270:270,                    % <---
    samples=181,
    no marks                            % <---
            ]
\draw[very thin, densely dashed]        % <--- moved before *addšlpt*
    (-270,-2.2) -- (-270,2.2)
    (-90,-2.2) -- (-90,2.2)
    (90,-2.2) -- (90,2.2)
    (270,-2.2) -- (270,2.2);
\addplot +[red,very thick] {tan(x)};    % <---
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

- In cases, that you have many similar images, you can common parts of axis definition move into `\pgfplotsset` in preamble and locally write only specific for images.
- With added fonts declaration also works your MWE and gives the same result in pdf viewers and on the paper:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
    \usefonttheme{professionalfonts}    % <---
\usepackage{unicode-math}               % <---
    \setsansfont{Verdana}               % <---
    \setmathfont{XITS Math}             % <---

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
        \draw[thick,->] (-5.1,0) -- (5.1,0)node[pos=1,right]{
        $x$};
        \draw[thick,->] (0,-4) -- (0,4)node[pos=1,left]{$y$};
    \node[below right](o) at (-0.1,0.1){$0$};
        \begin{scope}
        \clip (-5.1,-4) rectangle (5.1,4);
       \draw[dashed](-1.57,-4)--(-1.57,-0.8);
       \draw[dashed](-1.57,-0.1)--(-1.57,4);
       \draw[dashed](1.57,-4)--(1.57,4);
       \draw[dashed](4.71,-4)--(4.71,4);
       \draw[dashed](-4.71,-4)--(-4.71,4);
        \draw[ultra thick, red, domain={-1.5 }:{1.5}, samples=200] plot(\x,{tan(((\x))*180/pi)});
        \draw[ultra thick, red, domain={-4.7 }:{-1.7}, samples=200] plot(\x,{tan(((\x))*180/pi)});
        \draw[ultra thick, red, domain={1.6 }:{4.7}, samples=200] plot(\x,{tan(((\x))*180/pi)});
        \end{scope}
     \node[below]() at (-3.14,0){$-π$};
     \node[below]() at (3.14,0){$π$};
     \node[below]() at (-1.8,0.1){$-\dfrac{π}{2}$};
     \node[below left]() at (4.9,0.1){$\dfrac{3π}{2}$}; % <---
     \node[below right]() at (1.32,0.1){$\dfrac{π}{2}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

however, the result is to my opinion not so nice as at use of `pgfplots`:

[image]

- In both examples result is the same on paper or in pdf viewer.
- In both MWE are marked code lines which in comparison to MWE in question are added or changed.